# One example in database manipulation in SQL

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I'm trying to write a query that contains that the employees who have at least 2 children with height less than 170cm and the number of these children.

This is the table definition of each table 'employee' and 'child'

```
CREATE TABLE Employee(
    ID CHAR(10) PRIMARY KEY,
    SSN CHAR(15) NOT NULL,
    FNAME CHAR(15),
    LNAME CHAR(15),
    DOB DATE NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE Child(
    ID CHAR(10),
    NAME CHAR(15),
    HEIGHT NUMBER,
    PRIMARY KEY(ID,NAME),
    FOREIGN KEY(ID) REFERENCES Employee(ID) ON DELETE CASCADE
);
```

This is the query I'm producing now:

```
SELECT e.ID, COUNT(*) AS NumberOfChildren 
    FROM Employee e JOIN Child c ON e.ID = c.ID 
    WHERE c.HEIGHT > 170 
    GROUP BY c.ID 
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1;
```

it doesn't compile, could anyone help me with it? Thanks.

Comment: You call id from employee.. But group by id in child.. What do you expect?

Comment: i think the id of child and employee points to the same id like definition indicated

Comment: `GROUP BY e.ID` and your query should work.

Answer (score 0):

First You do this query.. And add `Proper Join` even `Join` and `Inner Join` are equivalent..

```
SELECT 
   e.ID, 
   COUNT(e.*) AS NumberOfChildren 
FROM 
   Employee e 
   INNER JOIN Child c ON e.ID = c.ID AND c.HEIGHT > 170
GROUP BY 
   e.ID
HAVING 
   COUNT(e.*) > 1;
```

EDIT:

As i see in your comment.. Definition `Group By` are to do `Group By` with all `Select` expression without `Aggregate Condition`..

Answer (score 0):

change the "GROUP BY c.ID" to "GROUP BY e.ID".

```
SELECT e.ID, COUNT(*) AS NumberOfChildren 
FROM Employee e JOIN Child c ON e.ID = c.ID 
WHERE c.HEIGHT > 170 
GROUP BY e.ID 
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

Answer (score 0):

On your query, group by clause given to e.ID rather than c.ID

```
SELECT e.ID, COUNT(e.*) AS NumberOfChildren 
    FROM Employee e JOIN Child c ON e.ID = c.ID 
    WHERE c.HEIGHT > 170 
    GROUP BY e.ID 
    HAVING COUNT(e.*) > 1;
```